# Is there a way to make sure a C++ .h matches the corresponding C++ .cpp file?

Tags: c++, compilation, java-native-interface, javah

The code in question is a JNI interface between a Java and a native code.
The h file is produced by the javah utility, whereas the cpp file is created by human.

If the Java part is renamed then javah produces function prototypes with the corresponding names, like it should. However, nothing makes sure the functions in the cpp file are renamed as well - all compiles as usual. The problem will only arise when the Java code invokes the native API at runtime.

How could one catch a mismatch between the h file produced by javah and the implementation cpp file produced by human during the compilation?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a static code analyzer or linter.

Comment: Great, please provide a working example, so that your reply could be accepted as the answer.

Comment: There are several different software packages that provide this functionality, and I don't know a specific one that does exactly what you want - but this should give you a starting point to *look* for a product that meets your needs...

Comment: I fixed that with [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) by generating the whole .cpp source file, not just the .h header file like `javah`.

Comment: @SamuelAudet Would you consider your code production ready?

Comment: Well, JavaCPP itself not really no, but I'm opened to suggestions about its future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about referring to the generated function declarations somewhere in the C++ code?

E.g. in (say) `generated_check.cpp` create a function that calls your prototypes with dummy parameters (but never call it):

```
#include "generated.h" // your javah output

static void neverCalled() {
     // Compiler errors here mean that the functions have changed:
     Java_com_example_package_MyClass_myFunc1(0, 0, 0);
     Java_com_example_package_MyClass_myFunc2(0);
}
```

**Edit, in response to your comments:**

Another (or complementary) approach would be to create a script that runs as part of your build process and have it back up the old `generated.h` before javah is run, and cause a build error if the new `generated.h` is different to the old one. It could even run a *diff* program to give you an error message to pinpoint the change.

Comment: This is a great idea. Let me check it.

Comment: This answers the case when the Java code is renamed, then the compiler fails the build, just what I want. There is a downside - the dev must have the discipline to add new methods to neverCalled.  +1 in the meantime.

Comment: It would be nice, though, to be protected not only against renames, but also against the parameter type changes. In your solution (which is great) one will have to cast the zeros to the respected types to achieve this effect, which is a bit dull.

Comment: Yes, true -- Added an alternative approach in the main answer.